# Coq how to target and transform hypotheses to show that they're false?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove that if two lists of booleans are equal (using a definition of equality that walks the lists structurally in the obvious way), then they have the same length.

In the course of doing so, however, I end up in a situation with a hypothesis that is false/uninhabited, but not literally `False` (and thus can't be targeted by the `contradiction` tactic).

Here's what I have so far.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Export Coq.Bool.Bool.

Require Import Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Open Scope list_scope.
Open Scope nat_scope.



Fixpoint list_bool_eq (a : list bool) (b: list bool) : bool :=
  match (a, b) with
  | ([], []) => true
  | ([], _) => false
  | (_, []) => false
  | (true::a', true::b') => list_bool_eq a' b'
  | (false::a', false::b') => list_bool_eq a' b'
  | _ => false
  end.

Fixpoint length (a : list bool) : nat :=
  match a with
  | [] => O
  | _::a' => S (length a')
  end.

Theorem equal_implies_same_length : forall (a b : list bool) , (list_bool_eq a b) = true ->  (length a) = (length b).
intros.
induction a.
induction b.
simpl. reflexivity.
```

After this, the "goal state" (what's the right word?) of coq as shown by coqide looks like this.

```
2 subgoals
a : bool
b : list bool
H : list_bool_eq [] (a :: b) = true
IHb : list_bool_eq [] b = true -> length [] = length b
______________________________________(1/2)
length [] = length (a :: b)
______________________________________(2/2)
length (a :: a0) = length b
```

Clearing away some of the extraneous detail...

```
Focus 1.
clear IHb.
```

We get

```
1 subgoal
a : bool
b : list bool
H : list_bool_eq [] (a :: b) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
length [] = length (a :: b)
```

To us, as humans, `length [] = length (a :: b)` is clearly false/uninhabited, but that's okay because `H : list_bool_eq [] (a :: b) = true` is false too.

However, the hypothesis `H` is not literally `False`, so we can't just use `contradiction`.

How do I target/"focus my attention from the perspective of Coq" on the hypothesis `H` so I can show that it's uninhabited. Is there something roughly analogous to a proof bullet `-, +, *, { ... }` that creates a new context inside my proof specifically for showing that a given hypothesis is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simplify your hypothesis (`simpl in H`), you will see that it is equivalent to `false = true`. At that point, you can conclude the goal with the `easy` tactic, which is capable of discharging such "obvious" contradictions even when they are syntactically equal to `False`. As a matter of fact, you should not even need to perform the simplification beforehand; `easy` should be powerful enough to figure out what is contradictory by itself.

(It would have been better to prove the following stronger result: `forall l1 l2, list_bool_eq l1 l2 = true <-> l1 = l2`.)